# Dependency of two decision variables on Cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

my Problem in OPL CPLEX 12.9.0 is the following.
I have two decision variables with a lower and an upper bound for each one.

```
decision_variable_1 >= decision_variable_1_min;
decision_variable_1 <= decision_variable_1_max;
decision_variable_2 >= decision_variable_2_min;
decision_variable_2 <= decision_variable_2_max;
```

---

I want to decide:

If `decision_variable_1` choose `decision_variable_1_min`;
Similarly, if `decision_variable_2` then `decision_variable_2_min` should also be choose.

`decision_variable_1_min`, `decision_variable_1_max`, `decision_variable_2_min`, and `decision_variable_2_max` are floats.

---

It's not easy to explain but I hope someone understands my problem.

Comment: What are the types of `decision_variable_1` and `decision_variable_2`? Are they binary?

Comment: Your problem description is not clear. What do you mean by "if `decision_variable_1`"? And what does "then choose `decision_variable_1_min`"?
Do you mean that `decision_variable_1` should be either 0 or `decision_variable_1_min`? Or do you mean that `decision_variable_1` should be either 0 or a value between `decision_variable_1_min` and `decision_variable_1_max`? Or do you mean something completely different?

Comment: decision_variable_1 and decision_variable_2 are not binary, they are normal       dvar float+ decision variables.

Comment: decision_variable_1 should be a value between decision_variable_1_min and decision_variable_1_max. But what I try to do is to connect decision_variable_1 with decision_ variable_2. So if decision_variable_1 == decision_variable_1_ min then decision_variable_2 == decision_variable_2_ min and not decision_variable_2_max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment made the question clear:

> what I try to do is to connect `decision_variable_1` with `decision_variable_2`. So if `decision_variable_1 == decision_variable_1_min` then
>   `decision_variable_2 == decision_variable_2_min`

This can be done using [logical constraints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_types_logical.html), in this case the "implies" constraint which is represented by the `=>` operator:

```
(decision_variable_1 == decision_variable_1_min) => (decision_variable_2 == decision_variable_2_min);
```